# QGIS making points to path permanent

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I'm using the "Points to path" processing tool.  It works fine but it is not saved when I exit QGIS.  It shows up in layers panel but not on screen on restart.  I tried making the scratch layer permanent and got this error message

> Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent.
>
> Error: Creation of
> data source failed (OGR error: sqlite3_open(arrows.gpkg) failed:
> unable to open database file)

I don't know enough to interpret the error or correct it.  I presume I'm doing something wrong when I initiate Point to path but cannot see any obvious options to correct.

Comment: Have you tried saving in a different data format? Does the tool work properly with other point-data as input?

Comment: Do you mean the layer or whole project Erik?  The tool works fine, only problem is it's not saved with the rest on exit, it's still in layers panel but not on screen when re opened.

Comment: The layer. Have you saved it manually before closing QGIS?

Comment: I have tried (I'm fairly sure) all the options for saving the layer but it still says

Comment: This project includes one or more temporary scratch layers. These layers are not saved to disk and their contents will be permanently lost. Are you sure you want to proceed?

Comment: Then you didn't save the layers. Period.

Comment: @Erik I don't understand why it wants me to tell it where I want to save the layer and in what format.  I want to save it as part of the project, not separately!

Answer (score 3):

This error is likely due to the fact that you enter just the name you want in the file name field when the proper way is to enter a full path. (just click on the box with 3 point on the right of the field to access the explorator)

[image]

The file name field let you create a new geopackage or select an existing one (so you can add several layer to the same .gpkg) , the layer name is automaticaly set with the same name as the .gpkg but you can change it.

Comment: Wouldn't let me add to existing .gpkg but worked OK when I renamed.

Comment: I don't understand why it wants me to tell it where I want to save the layer and in what format. I want to save it as part of the project, not separately!